# Integrating over a paraboloid, help on determining limits of integrations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

Calculate the integral: $$ \int \int \int _{\Omega}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\ dx\ dy\ dz   $$
Where $\Omega$ it's the region bounded by $y\ =\ x^2 +z^2$ and the plane $y\ =\ 4$

I've performed a change of coordinates to cilindrical considering $y$ as my height so $$\int \int \int _{\Omega}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\ dx\ dy\ dz\ =\ \int\int\int r^2\ dy\ dr\ d\theta$$

Now i'm having a hard time on setting the itegration limits I've tried with

$r^2 \leqslant y \leqslant 4$, $0\leqslant r\leqslant 2$, $0\leqslant \theta\ \leqslant 2\pi$

Are this well set?

Comment: Should one of your $x^2$'s be a $z^2$?

Comment: Maybe we have $\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ as function to be integrated?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I'll correct it, it should be as you say @gimusi

Comment: @FernandoL.R. Ok, I've updated the set up accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By cylindrical coordinates

- $x=r\cos \theta$
- $z=r\sin \theta$
- $y=y$

we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^4 dy \int _0^\sqrt yy\,r\ dr$$

Comment: So that's how the integral looks after performing the coordinates change and setting well the limits? Sorry but, I'dont see why it get's like that

Comment: @FernandoL.R. We are integrating on planes with $y=const.$ therefore $\theta$ goes around from $0$ to $2\pi$, $y$ goes from $0$ to $4$ and in each plane $y=const.$ $r$ goes from $0$ to $\sqrt y$. The $y$ term in the integral is the function $\sqrt{x^2+z^2}=y$ and $r$ is the term from the jacobian.

Comment: @FernandoL.R. Later I will make a sketch to make things more clear!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've donde the itegral it gets like $\frac{\pi 2^{11/2}}{15}$

Comment: By the way, do you know how to upload images here?

Comment: @FernandoL.R. Refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And therefore your integral is$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_{r^2}^4f(r\cos\theta,y,r\sin\theta)r\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta,$$where $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}=r$.

Comment: Thanks, I've integrated over that and the result is far away from what you would call a "nice" result, I mean $\approx 300$. Anyway I'll stick to it!